# Getting test cases skipped in CHelper plugin for IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I am using CHelper plugin for IntelliJ Idea. Every time I write code and compile it, I get output like:

> Test #0: SKIPPED
>
> ---
>
> Test #1: SKIPPED
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> Test #2: SKIPPED
>
> ---
>
> Test #3:
>   Input:
>   10 4
>    40 10 20 70 80 10 20 70 80 60
>
> Expected output:
>   40
>   Execution result:
>   70
>
> Verdict: Wrong Answer (Difference in token #0) in 0.000 s.
>
> ## ------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Test results:
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Here the output for Test #4 was wrong. But if the output is correct for all test cases, the following output is shown:

> Test #0: Input: 5 3 10 30 40 50 20
>
> Expected output: 30
>
> Execution result: 30
>
> Verdict: OK in 0.000 s.
>
> ---
>
> Test #1: Input: 3 1 10 20 10
>
> Expected output: 20
>
> Execution result: 20
>
> Verdict: OK in 0.001 s.
>
> ---
>
> Test #2: Input: 2 100 10 10
>
> Expected output: 0
>
> Execution result: 0
>
> Verdict: OK in 0.000 s.
>
> ---
>
> Test #3: Input: 10 4 40 10 20 70 80 10 20 70 80 60
>
> Expected output: 70 Execution result: 70
>
> Verdict: OK in 0.000 s.
>
> ## ------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Test results: All test passed input 0.001 s.
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I am unable to understand why the test cases are being skipped. Can anybody explain why this is happening? And if yes, how to prevent the test cases from being skipped.

Answer (score 0):

When smart testing is enabled in CHelper, if one of the testcases fails, the rest of the testcases will be skipped.

To disable smart testing:

1. Click on `Edit`>`Project`>`Settings` in the toolbar. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyCh2.png)
2. In `Project Settings`, uncheck `Use smart testing`. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdR1M.png)